# Accounting for errors in independent variable through Gaussian process regression

Tags: regression, scikit-learn, error, gaussian-process, uncertainty

In Gaussian process regression (GPR), one applies a kernel (i.e. covariance function) to describe the similarity between observed and predicted data in the domain. The diagonal of the covariance function accounts for noise in the dependent or response variable. But is there an analogous method to errors-in-variables models (e.g. total least squares) to account for error in the independent or explanatory variable(s) inherently in GPR?

Comment: It might be possible that Orthogonal Distance Regression can help in your modeling work. From the scipy docs on ODR: "Why Orthogonal Distance Regression (ODR)? Sometimes one has measurement errors in the explanatory (a.k.a., “independent”) variable(s), not just the response (a.k.a., “dependent”) variable(s). Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) fitting procedures treat the data for explanatory variables as fixed, i.e., not subject to error of any kind." I can post a simple scipy.odr example if it might be useful.

Comment: Exactly, I was considering ODR but curious about combining it with GPR. Or if there are existing techniques within GPR to handle uncertainty in the explanatory variable. Sensitivity analysis could be an alternative viable approach, but I wanted to confirm if I was overlooking GPR's capability and advancements in tackling this sort of problem.